# How to make website adapt to different size of phone screens?

Tags: ios, css, iphone, html

I made a website which needs to look in an exactly same way on all the screens.
I designed it with width = 320 and auto height.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320">
```

Now no matter what size of the screen the website scales nicely to fit the screen. It's important for me that the website SCALES and not RESIZES so I cannot use in this case this code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

But while it works fine on various phone emulators and a few different smartphones it doesn't scale on **iPhone 6**. It just shows the whole website in the top,left corner with black bars on the right and bottom.

How can I force iPhone 6 to zoom the page so this 320px is zoomed to match iPhone's screen width?

Answer (score 1):

using viewport may not be the best option for your case.
I think it could be better if you use [css @media](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) because you need to have width = 100%

for example

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
div {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}}
```

so no matter if user uses iphone 6 or iphone 4, the screen will be perfect.